# How to use onActivityResult method from other than Activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I am creating an app where i need to find current location of user .

So here I would like to do a task like when user returns from that System  intent, my task should be done after that.(Displaying users current location)

So i am planning to use `OnActivityResult()`.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
```

But the problem is that I don't know how can I use that method in a class which is not extending Activity.

Please some one give me idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: follow this link http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/return-result-to-onactivityresult.html it may helps you

Comment: You cannot call that method in other classes. You should create the instance of that class in the activity and call the processing method there.

Comment: You can create blank transparent activity for this, and return result to your task from it's onActivityResult().

Comment: Where are you calling this from??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally i got what i need and also the solution for this question.

```
 Activity con;
Intent intent_= new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            con.startActivityForResult(intent_, 0);
```

Now i can create a method here,

```
public void startActivityForResult(Intent i, int code)
{
    Log.e("", "insede method startActivityForResult()");
}
```

By using this System is not creating a sub-activity for my intent so,this  method gets called only after user return from intent.

Comment: And where is the onActivityResult method?

Comment: This seems to be an uncompleted code. From your question it is understood that you need "OnActivityResult" method, where is it in your answer?

Answer (score 12):

You need an Activity on order to receive the result.

If its just for organisation of code then call other class from Activty class.

```
public class Result {
    public static void activityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
          ...
   }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       Result.activityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: i couldn't understand your logic.
Will you give a demo for that

Comment: I am doing something similar just for organising code for Facebook login, but the onActivityResult()  in Fragment doesn't get called after successful login attempt. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 6):

Create an inner class in the non Activity class and define your activity results handler therein:

```
class singletonActivity extends Activity{
  protected void onActivityResult(...){
    // do whatever ..
  }
}
```

intantiate it to call startActivityForResult

```
Activity actv = new singletonActivity(..)
actv.startActivityForResult(intent ..)
```

your handler will be called.
:)

ps: you may have to include some overrides. just leave them empty.

pps: this is old school java mouseListenerAdapter style 
~Oo>

Comment: Good idea, i was working on some third party project where i was not having access to main project code. your answer may solve my issue.

Comment: This gives an error `Unable to find explicit activity class {...} have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`. How should this be added to AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 5):

**You can't call this method out of his scope.**

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

If the method is **protected** like this case, you can see the table of **Access Levels** to know how to proceed.

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|                     ACCESS LEVELS                         |
|------------------|---------|---------|----------|---------|
|      Modifier    |  Class  | Package | Subclass |  World  |
|------------------|---------|---------|----------|---------|
|      public      |    Y    |    Y    |    Y     |    Y    |
|------------------|---------|---------|----------|---------|
|      protected   |    Y    |    Y    |    Y     |    N    |
|------------------|---------|---------|----------|---------|
|      no modifier |    Y    |    Y    |    N     |    N    |
|------------------|---------|---------|----------|---------|
|      private     |    Y    |    N    |    N     |    N    |
|------------------|---------|---------|----------|---------|
```

As you can see, this method only can be called from `android.app.*` package, `Activity` and their subclasses.

---

**SOLUTION:**

You need to do something like this:

We have a class `ImagePicker` for selecting a image from **Gallery** or **Camera** or **Delete** it. This class need to call `onActivityResult` if user wants to delete image (We don't need to start an `Activity` for a result that we already know).

```
public class ImagePicker {
    private ImagePickerDelegate delegate;

    public ImagePicker (ImagePickerDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    //Will explain this two methods later
    public void show() {
        //Some code to show AlertDialog
    }

    public void handleResponse(Intent data) {
        //Some code to handle onActivityResult
    }

    //Our interface to delegate some behavior 
    public interface ImagePickerDelegate {
        void onImageHandled(Bitmap image);
        void onImageError();
        void onImageDeleted();
    }
}
```

For using this class in our `Activity`, we need to implement the delegate methods and pass our activity as the delegate of `ImagePicker`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ImagePicker.ImagePickerDelegate {
    ImagePicker imagePicker;    

    @OnClick(R.id.image_edit)
    public void selectImage () {
        imagePicker = new ImagePicker(this);
        imagePicker.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == ImagePicker.REQUEST_IMAGE_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imagePicker.handleResponse(data);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageHandled(Bitmap image) {
        //handle image resized
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageError() {
        //handle image error
        Toast.makeText(this, "Whoops - unexpected error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageDeleted() {
        //handle image deleted
        groupImageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        groupImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pick_picture);
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to make thous delegate methods to be called, and that happen in `show()` and `handleResponse(Intent data)`:

```
//The show method create and dialog with 3 options,
//the important thing here, is when an option is selected
public void show() {
    //Inflating some views and creating dialog...

    NavigationView navView = (NavigationView)viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.navigation_menu);
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener( new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_select_image:
                    Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , REQUEST_IMAGE_PICKER);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_take_picture:
                    Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(takePicture, REQUEST_IMAGE_PICKER);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_delete_image:
                    delegate.onImageDeleted(); //send response to activity
                    break;
            }
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
    });

    //Show dialog...
}


//this method is called from onActivityResult
public void handleResponse(Intent data) {
    try {
        //Retrieve and resize image...
        delegate.onImageHandled(image); //send the image to activity
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        delegate.onImageError(); //send error to activity
    }
}
```

At the end, what we have, is a `class` that can call a method in your `Activity` instead of `onActivityResult`, but when you get a result in `onActivityResult`, you need to handle it in that `class`

Comment: This is the correct answer to this and all those similar questions on SO. It should have more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register an `Activity` to this class and then use `OnActivityResult()` for that activity.

Answer (score 1):

When you start an `activity` with `startActivityForResult` method from an `activity`, only the caller will receive the result.

So you could handle the result and pass it to the task or update the UI of that `activity`:

```
int MY_REQUEST_ID = 1;

public void onClick(){
    //Select a contact.
    startActivityForResult(
             new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             new Uri("content://contacts")),
             MY_REQUEST_ID);
}    

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if(requestCose == MY_REQUEST_ID && resultCode == SUCCESS) {
         MyAsyncTask task = new AsyncTask(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         task.execute();
         // or update the UI
         textView.setText("Hi, activity result: "+ resultCode);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using it like this this may be helpful to others

In my fragment I have

```
// Upload Cover Photo On Button Click
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Start The Image Cropper And Go To onActivityResult
        Intent intent = ImageManager.startImageCropper(getContext());
        startActivityForResult(intent, CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    }
});
```

Then Calling The Result Like This In The Fragment

```
// On Activity Result for Start Activity For Result
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Get The Image From Image Cropper
    Uri resultUri = ImageManager.activityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, getContext());
}
```

The public class / functions supporting these are

```
public class ImageManager {

    // Start Image Cropper
    public static Intent startImageCropper(Context context) {

        // Crop Image
        Intent intent = CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setActivityTitle("Title")
                .setCropMenuCropButtonTitle("Save")
                .setAutoZoomEnabled(true)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .getIntent(context);

        return intent;

    }

    public static Uri activityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data, Context context) {

        // Handle Cropped Image

        Uri resultUri = null;

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                resultUri = result.getUri();

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
                Toast.makeText(context, (CharSequence) error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        return resultUri;
    }
}
```

Comment: perfect answer!