# How to use onActivityResult in another class

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I want to use onActivityResult in a class which not extends activity but this class has a global variable as an instance of activity. This class is similar to this :

```
public class myClass(){
    public Activity myActivity;
    .
    .
    .
    // I want to add onMyActivityResult here
}
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
myActivity.setOnActivityResult...
```

Thanks!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780252/how-to-use-onactivityresult-method-from-other-than-activity-class

Comment: don't do this. if you still want to do this, research carefully about Activity's lifecycle, then don't do this

Comment: please try my answer and tell me if it works for you ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could do the following

```
public class myClass(){

    public static void activityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

          //right your code here .
   }
}
```

and in your **CLASS EXTENDS ACTIVITY** write this inside the onActivityResult Method :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       myClass.activityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }
```

thnx to this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/21780532/3818437

Comment: I didn't used this method but I used a method almost like this and it works!

Comment: Wouldn't it better to implement an interface than a static method?

Comment: @abarazal yes its better to avoid static methods

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to override of instance onActivityResult() but it is possible to do the way below.
The major idea is to create your class which calls your custom function inside the code;
In this case

That is, your activity class have to be extended by ABase not by Activity:

```
public class yourClass extends ABase{
//your usual code is here.
}
```

Then, `ABase` looks like this:

```
public class ABase extends Activity {
private Callable<Void> clb;//this function will be called
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (clb != null) {
                        try {
                        clb.call();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
}
public void setMyCallable(Callable<Void> callable){
this.clb = callable;
}
}
```

in your public myClass use `public ABase` act instead of `public Activity act`;
there is a `setSomeFunction()` for example to use:

```
public class myClass {
public ABase act;
public static setSomeFunction() {
    if (act != null) {
        Callable<Void> clb = new Callable<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws Exception {
                    Log.d(TAG, "is Called!");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        act.setMyCallable(clb);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    public interface IResult {
        void call(Intent data);
    }

    public IResult r;


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
        if (r == null) return;

        r.call(data);
    }

    void startZ() { Z.startZ(this); }
    void startY() { Y.startY(this); }
}
```

Z

```
class Z {
    public static void startZ(MyActivity a) {
        a.r = data -> {
            //...YOUR CODE HERE...
        };

        a.startActivityForResult(
                new Intent(a, ZActivity.class),
                request_code___not_needed_because_only_one_activity_lives);
    }
}
```

Y

```
class Y {
    public static void startY(MyActivity a) {
        a.r = data -> {
            //...YOUR CODE HERE...
        };

        a.startActivityForResult(
                new Intent(a, YActivity.class),
                request_code___not_needed_because_only_one_activity_lives);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining lifecycle for activity result is more stable

First declare a class

```
class MyLifecycleObserver implements DefaultLifecycleObserver {

    private final ActivityResultRegistry mRegistry;

    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mGetContent;

    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mGetSecondContent;

    MyLifecycleObserver(@NonNull ActivityResultRegistry registry) {
        mRegistry = registry;
    }

    public void onCreate(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
        // ...

        mGetContent = mRegistry.register("details_action", owner, new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // There are no request codes
                Intent data = result.getData();
                
            }
        });

        mGetSecondContent = mRegistry.register("location_action", owner, new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void actionLauncher(Intent intent) {
        // Open the activity to select an image
        mGetContent.launch(intent);
    }

    public void locationLauncher() {
        // Open the activity to select an image
        mGetSecondContent.launch(new Intent(requireActivity(), LocationPickerActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Here you can set multiple launch and its actions

with the KEY you can now register or unregister an Activity Result as per your requirement.

now using this class in a fragment

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
private MyLifecycleObserver mObserver;

@Override
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    mObserver = new MyLifecycleObserver(requireActivity().getActivityResultRegistry());
    getLifecycle().addObserver(mObserver);
}

@Override
void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Button selectButton = findViewById(R.id.select_button);
    selectButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mObserver.locationLauncher();
        }
    });}}
```

now set result from your desired activity and you are all set