# Implementing onActivityResult in a nonActivity Java Class

Tags: java, android, proxy, android-ndk, native-activity

I am working on to capture image function through Intent call.

I have been successful in implementing startActivityforResult from non-Activity class. I am getting activity Context there.

Now, I want to receive onActivityResult in same java class.
As I know it's compulsory to have Activity class to receive this method.

Will it be possible?

I tried to call with [Java Proxy](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) ,  [InvocationHandler link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) but I didn't get success.

code:

```
public class NovusAPI {

    private Context mContext;
    private NativeActivity nativeactivity;
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor. Save reference to NativeActivity object
     **/
    NovusAPI(NativeActivity ref) {

        nativeactivity = ref;
        Log.d(TAG, "NovusAPI constructor called");

    }

    public void captureImage(){
            Log.d(TAG, "Image Capture Call");
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "novus");
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "novus camera capture");

            // capture image camera
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            nativeactivity.startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

       }
```

**EDIT:**

```
PreferenceManager Class:
  public interface OnActivityResultListener {

        /**
         * See Activity's onActivityResult.
         * 
         * @return Whether the request code was handled (in which case
         *         subsequent listeners will not be called.
         */
        boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
    }
```

OnActivityResultListener is interface for Android Preference class.
So,I do to work on this to InvocationHanlder link.

Comment: I think you can do it similarly a you called startActivityForResult. Though you will have to register a function with your event onActivityResult as you can't implement it here.

Comment: See this answer if it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21793981/2555668

Comment: NativeActivity & Activity. Please review my code again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two option -

1. You can create `NovusBaseActivity` that extends `Activity`, you'll not need to pass `context`. In `NovusBaseActivity` you can start intent and get result in `onActivityResult`. instead of passing activity context to `NovusAPI`, extends `NovusBaseActivity`.
2. As suggested in the comment's answer - 
   In activity's `onActivityResult`, call result handling method from `NovusAPI` using `NovusAPI` instance that you have created previously to call `captureImage`.

Comment: How can I force an Activity to call the method ?