# Android pass onActivityResult() to another class

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

Firstly, I have a function with result callback that starts another activity:

```kotlin
object Functions {
  fun myFunction(context: Context, onResult: (resultCode: Int) -> Unit) {
    context.startActivity(Intent(context, DelegateActivity::class.java))
  }
}
```

Secondly, I have DelegateActivity (that receives a result from ResultActivity) and ResultActivity:

```kotlin
class DelegateActivity : Activity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    startActivityForResult(Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java))
  }
  
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
     // TODO: send result to onResult(resultCode) callback!
  }
}

class ResultActivity : Activity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // some code with setResult()
  }  
}
```

My problem is that I have to forward the result from DelegateActivity to the onResult() - It's a requirement. How can I do this?

I can use EventBus/RxBus, but is there a better way?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780252/how-to-use-onactivityresult-method-from-other-than-activity-class

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use `onActivityResult` directly in the Activity/Fragment that you are using to call this `Functions.myFunction`? If you try to do what you're describing, you will leak your Activity and it won't work if there is a configuration change during the time the second activity is open.

Comment: @Tenfour04, it is a library requirement.

Comment: Can you share which library it is? I think either you have a misunderstanding about how to use the library, or the library has a flawed design that will leak activities.

Comment: So its my library. There will be no leaks with EventBus, I realized it, but I am finding better solution.